# Difficulty to intrepret pvclust results - only many low level tree clusters appear as significant

Tags: r, clustering, bootstrap

I'm trying to assess the uncertainty in hierarchical cluster analysis. It is a dataset composed of 409 observations and 27 variables (with a value ranging form 0 to 100). The dataset represents immunohistochemical scores in a gastrointestinal cancers.

A meaninful clustering of observations and markers is observed with Pearson uncentered distance and average linkage.

```
hc <- hclust(Dist(t(imputedMatrix), method="pearson"), method="average")
hr <- hclust(Dist(imputedMatrix, method="pearson"), method="average")
heatmap.2(imputedMatrix, Rowv=as.dendrogram(hr), Colv=as.dendrogram(hc),   col=greenred(100), scale="none", ColSideColors=patientcolors, density.info="none", trace="none")

pv2 <- pvclust(imputedMatrix, method.dist="uncentered", method.hclust="average", nboot=10000)
plot(pv2, hang=-1)
pvrect(pv2, alpha=0.95)

clsig <- unlist(pvpick(pv2, alpha=0.90, pv="au", type="geq", max.only=TRUE)$clusters) 
dend_colored <- dendrapply(as.dendrogram(pv2$hclust), dendroCol, keys=clsig,     xPar="edgePar", bgr="black", fgr="red", pch=20)
heatmap.2(imputedMatrix, Rowv=as.dendrogram(hr), Colv=dend_colored, col=greenred(1
```

However, when using pvclust to assess their uncertainty, many small low-levels subclusters are highlighted as significant, but not any higher level one. Also, a group of tumours (to the right in the plots) is indeed a control group that should be clearly distinguished at the highest level from the other ones. pvclust shows even there the same kind of pattern.

Indeed the clusters of interest are the magenta, green and red in the color bar. Does this pvclust results support their existance (versus a clustering artefact by chance)?

How could these pvclust results be interpreted? Maybe I am using the tool in a wrong way? Or the wrong tool for this kind of data?

Thank you very much in advance.

[image: pvclust dendrogram]
[image: hclust and pvclust, the latter in red in the dendrogram]

Answer (score 2):

If certain clusters are interesting and useful, then I would say that is enough to merit further investigation.

That further investigation could consist of:

1. Doing something similar on another data set (ideally, you would have split this one in two and used one for validation, but that isn't always realistic if sample sizes are small)
2. Taking means/medians etc. of these clusters on variables that either were or were not used in the clustering (but be careful to distinguish one from the other)
3. Making substantive notes on how the clusters differ and how they inform the literature.

I doubt that anything about statistical significance would be more important than these things.

Comment: Yes, the chanllenge is deciding the best strategy for (at this moment) internal validation of results.

Comment: Would this be correct?a) perform differential expression analysis between these three clusters of interest (tumour groups) to know the significant markers for their distinction; b)internally validate the model (profiles)by using another statistical procedure,eg. developing a classifier for these three groups as classes based on the significant markers and perform cross validation;or test their reproducibility and replication with OPLS-DA first will all markers and then only with the significant?

Comment: That certainly seems reasonable to me. I don't know anything about tumor diagnosis and classification, though.